# Как сохранить в кодировку utf-16-le with bom?

Tags: python

Есть код, который сохраняет данные в формат utf-16-le. Как сохранить в utf-16-le bom?

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', mode='a', newline='', encoding='utf-16-le') as employee_file:
    writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=";")
    row = ['Job1', 'M']
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Я пробую вот так

```
with open(filename, mode='a',newline='', encoding='utf-16-le') as employee_file:
   writer = csv.writer(employee_file,delimiter=";")
   row= ['\ufeff']
   writer.writerow(row)
   row = ['Job1', 'M']
   writer.writerow(row)
```

Всё в принципе работает, но хочу сохранять автоматом, без записи `\ufeff` в начало?

Comment: Если открывать файл с указанием кодировки utf-16, то будет записываться в utf-16-le с bom.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было добавить в конец файла метку порядка байтов `\ufeff`

```
def addUTF8Bom(filename):
  f = codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-16-le')
  content = f.read()
  f.close()
  f2 = codecs.open(filename, 'w', 'utf-16-le')
  f2.write(u'\ufeff')
  f2.write(content)
  f2.close()
```

Comment: Нужно добавлять в начало файла, не в конец

Comment: мне надо в конец)

Comment: Это странное требование. BOM - это чисто техническая штука, которая сама по себе не особо нужна, а если нужна - то нужна только в начале.